# PL/SQL script for export database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to export all the data from a database like functions, procedures, views, triggers for which an user has owner privilegies. I know that SQL Developer has the option for exporting databases in sql file, but I want to do this from the code. When I run the code I want to create a file with .sql extension which must contain all data from the database. First of all, I want to know if that is possible, and if it is, can anyone tell me some hints for doing this? 
I started with making a file:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY test_dir AS 'H:\';

DECLARE
   out_File  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  out_File := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('test_dir', 'test.sql' , 'W');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(out_file , 'here will be the database export');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(out_file);
END;
```

Comment: First, are you trying to create a file on your client's `h:\` drive or on the server's `h:\` drive?  `utl_file` can only write to files on the database server.  Does the code run?  Does it do what you expect?  Does it throw an error?  It is certainly possible to query `user_source`, call `dbms_metadata`, etc. to get all the information that you want.  I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.

Comment: I'm trying to put all functions, procedures, views, triggers made over time by me in sql developer in a .sql file..the part with creating directory and the file is the starting point, I read some article on web, but it doesn't work..I really don't know how to do this in code..that's why i'm looking some hints

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean to you?  Are you getting an error?  What error?  Is the file not being created?  Is the data in the file not what you expect?  Is the code that you posted working fine but some other piece of code that, say, writes out the procedure code not working?  Why do you want to write code to replicate what SQL Developer already does for you?

Comment: I need the code for a project at faculty..and the part which doesn't work is that the file isn't created, and I have some error like: "Error(3,18): PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_FILE' must be declared" or "Error(11,4): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed"

Comment: OK.  Has your user been given privileges on the `utl_file` package?  I'm guessing that you'll need to ask your DBA for that.

Comment: Yes, I understand the part with the privileges, I solve this one. But any idea about the code which must do the export?

Comment: I guess I'm back to not understanding what you're asking.  If I understand your last update, you now have a piece of code now that works correctly.  What additional question are you asking?  There are lots (and lots) of data dictionary tables and procedures that give you information about database objects.  I mentioned a couple in my initial comment.  You'd have to query/ call those and write the data out.  If you're saying that this is a homework assignment, I would assume that you're studying the various data dictionary tables.

Comment: I just need an info that whether you need to DDL for these objects or want an DB Export?

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle export/import utilities will export/import database objects in user mode (use OWNER parameter) using a binary file format

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/exp_imp.htm

However, if you want to export the metadata for your objects and data into sql files, you can query Oracle's catalog users views like user_objects -> for a user's database objects  user_tables -> tables, user_constraints -> constraints (even user_source to get text for compiled objects).  If you intend your .sql files to re-create objects and data, you are in for some heavy lifting, especially if you want your scripts to be portable.  In that case I would look 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be the answer for what you are looking for. Hope it helps. This is just an example for what you are asking. Other types can also be incorporated as required.

```
spool on;
spool <target path>/filename;

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN
  (SELECT al.*
  FROM ALL_SOURCE al
  WHERE OWNER = 'AVROY'
  ORDER BY name,
    line
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(I.TEXT);
  END LOOP;
  FOR I IN
  (SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'AVROY'
  )
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',i.table_name,'AVROY'));
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;

SPOOL OFF;
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the export and import utility of Oracle database.

http://www.oracle-dba-online.com/export_and_import.htm